# Missing digits of float when printing geojson data to console

Tags: python, json, geojson

I'm reading a massive geojson file in python. Whenever I print a set of coordinates the last decimal place gets dropped, even though it is present in the json file.

For example:

In the json file:

```
[110.888769531250034,19.991943359375]
```

When printed to the console:

```
[110.88876953125003,19.991943359375]
```

Here is the quick and dirty code I've been using to test why this is happening.

```py
import json

with open('world-json.json', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)


for i in data['features']:
    name = i.get('properties').get('ADMIN')
    coordinates = i.get('geometry').get('coordinates')

    if name == 'China':
        for i in coordinates:
            for p in i:
                for z in p:
                    print(z)
```

I've tried searching for why this is happening, but my google-fu is weak apparently.

Comment: The JSON literal has more digits than a Python `float` can preserve.

Comment: But really, are those degrees latitude? That many decimal places is claiming to specify a position at something like picometer accuracy.

Comment: you can use f-strings to change the format but it will return you a string. It will work if you only want print out the float.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I think [decimal library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) is just what you're looking for.

---

I don't know how your json looks, but suppose code will be like below.

```py
from decimal import * # ★ New line
import json

with open('world-json.json', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
  data = json.load(f)


for i in data['features']:
  name = i.get('properties').get('ADMIN')
  coordinates = map(Decimal, i.get('geometry').get('coordinates')) # ★ Changed line

  if name == 'China':
    for i in coordinates:
      for p in i:
        for z in p:
          print(str(z)) # ★ Changed line
```